# why stop importing sql file using command line

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line

I try to import a file which is 11G using command line, which is as below
`sudo mysql -u root -p dbname < sharing/mydb.sql`,

```
 result 
     [sudo] password for magedev: `//enter my password here`
result:
     not talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864,leaking memory
     Enter password: //enter password again, the same one as above
```

Then it displays nothing and when I refresh my phpadmin,. I notice it began importing, but it's confused that every time it uploads until 4.5 G, it seems that it stop importing, does where can I specify the maximum file size or something?

Comment: sudo? why sudo? mysql doesn't need root privs to run. you can log into the mysql 'root' user from system ANY account.

Answer (score 0):

This is different issues:
"not talloc stackframe at" - this is known samba bug

If you use samba on your linux server - just:

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

check off checkbox "SMB password synchronization"